# Badge balance out of whack

Tags: discussion, badges

Yes, another badges question.

SO seems to have reached the point where the "game balance" (for want of a better word) between badges has become badly distorted. The "tags" badges that get created on demand, for example, require a serious amount of real work to achieve, as evidenced by the number of people that have earned them (e.g. only 11 gold C++, only 27 silver java, and so on).

Contrast this with the huge number of gold "general" badges out there... 556 "great answers", 117 "famous questions", etc. These can be awarded for a single question or answer, and a quick trawl of a sample of them shows them all to be for our favourite "soft" questions.

OK, I'm not really sure where I'm going with this ramble, but is the color of the badge anything more than eye candy, if the balance is so distorted?

Answer (score 3):

A sizable number of the gold badges are being migrated to meta, as they were meta-questions.

They go from being "meta-gold" badges on SO to real gold badges on MSO.

Comment: Will they be removed from SO at some point?

Comment: Last I heard, the system just remembered that you "owe" it the badge-when one is migrated your count at the first site stays the same, but the next time you earn a badge there it's not incremented either.  But that was a rumor, and I'm not sure if there's any truth to it.